# How can I add namespace prefix to XML using XStream in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, xstream

I am using XStreamMarshaller of Spring batch to generate XML, how can I add prefix namespace to nodes?

```xml
<bean id="userUnmarshaller" 
                class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="user" value="com.app.User" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

My Java Object :

```java
package com.app;

public class User {

    int id;
    String username;
    String password;
    int age;

    //... getter and setter methods

}
```

I get now something like that :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <username>app</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <age>30</age>
    </user>
</users>
```

but my need is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:users>
    <ns2:user>
        <ns2:id>1</ns2:id>
        <ns2:username>app</ns2:username>
        <ns2:password>password</ns2:password>
        <ns2:age>30</ns2:age>
    </ns2:user>
</ns1:users>
```

I tried to add xstream alias annotation to User.java, but it doesn't seems to work.
I really appreciate any help you can provide, Thank you

Comment: I don't think XStream has native support for namespaces (it depends on parser configuration and it's limited). XStreamAlias is kind of a hack and doesn't always work. But what you want could be achieved quite easily with JAXB.

Comment: @helderdarocha yes maybe i should migrate the all app using JAXB, It's a pity to waste all the work already done with Xstream, thank you tho for your answer

Comment: @hb.Sara Have a look here reagarding namespaces and xml-header declaration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614399/removing-xml-declaration-in-xstream/20658078#20658078 When configuring XStream, you can also configure the default namespace and the writer and thus fine-tune the output. If you however want to use many different namespaces, use a better fitting (schema based) library for this (like JAXB). XStream is great if you want to serialize objects to xml (and back) without a schema.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you, I migrate to JaxB, it support better NameSpaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code where I have updated property **rootTagName** and **aliases entry key** as shown below:

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/users.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="userUnmarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="ns1:users" />
</bean>

<bean id="userUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <util:map id="aliases">
            <entry key="ns2:user" value="com.mkyong.User" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you Braj, I migrate to JaxB, it support better NameSpaces.